# Java: why is there a difference in memory usage between for- and while-loops?

Tags: java, loops, memory, java-8

I am reading an XML file and pushing its contents into a `ByteArrayOutputStream` as follows:

```
static final MY_XML_FILE = new File("...");

byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) MY_XML_FILE.length()];
    int bytesRead;
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    while ((bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1)
        output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
```

which works fine.

I didn't like the scope of `bytesRead` to be visible outside the `while`-loop, so I changed it  to a `for`-loop:

```
for (int bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer); bytesRead != -1; )
    output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
```

But this throws the following error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3236)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:113)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:140)
```

My question is this: should the two ways of looping not be identical? If not, then I would like to know how a `for` and `while` loop differ in memory usage in Java.

Comment: see the 1 in the condition of the loop: for (int bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer); bytesRead != 1; )

Comment: It looks like your condition changes from "!= -1" to "!= 1"?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Corrected the typo.

Comment: For loop is completely wrong. No update to the loop to the loop condition. Just keeps writing and writing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your for loop you are only setting `bytesRead` once, not every iteration like you do in the `while`. The `for`-equivalent of your while loop would be:

```
for( int bytesRead; (bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1; )
```

Or a different way:

```
for( int bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer); bytesRead != -1; bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer) )
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you never update `bytesRead` in your `for` loop that becomes a request for unlimited memory;

```
for (int bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer); bytesRead != 1; )
    output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
```

Should be something like (and check that `bytesRead` isn't -1)

```
for (int bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer); bytesRead != -1; ) {
    output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer);
}
```

And I really suggest that you try to [write dumb code](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/devinsight-1-139780.html).

Answer (score 0):

In the `for` loop, you are checking if `bytesRead != 1`; in the `while` loop, you are checking if `bytesRead != -1`.

Answer (score 0):

When in a for you assign the first read to bytesRead you are placing a starting value for bytesRead. That will never be called again. Ence, you are writing over and over again until you go out of memory since bytesRead will never be -1.

To be more precise, imagine a typical for: `for(int i =0;i<x;i++)`. As you can see from your typical for the int i = 0 is only called once.Put the reading inside the for and start bytesRead as 0.